# How can I have one component per one object in list?

Tags: mysql, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a chat app in react native, and I wondered how can create x number of chat-boxes. I already built a react-native component that take as input the message content (example below), how can I duplicate it and insert the relevant data from a list.

```
const myList = ["hello", "world"]
```

```
<MessageBox message={"message content here"} />
```

at the end I want it to be equal to this:

```
<MessageBox message={"hello"} />
<MessageBox message={"world"} />
```

note: I'm not sure if I'm clear enough about this question so if you guys need any clarifications just ask.

thank you all in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is abstract, so I'll offer an abstract answer.

RDBMS systems hold and deliver **tables**. (The tables they deliver are called **result sets**.) These tables are inherently **arrays** of zero or more objects laid out the same way as each other. In your case you seem to have columns named `message`, `sender`, and so forth.

(Inside the database tables are actually unordered **bags** of objects. You make result sets into ordered arrays of objects with `ORDER BY` clauses in SQL queries.)

So, you'll fetch the result set of messages, and in your code you'll generate a sequence of these `<MessageBox .../>` items, one per item in the result set.

Keep in mind that server code, not client code, interacts with MySQL.

Comment: thank you, let me clarify what I need: I already got the server side sorted out so for simplicity let's say the component MessageBox got only one input (message content) and I declared a const myList = ['hello', 'world']. What should I do to get at the end something that is worth to <MessageBox message={"hello"} /><MessageBox message={"world"} />. I really have no idea how to do it, it resembles a for loop but I have no idea how to implant it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this

```
{myList.map(message => <MessageBox message={message} />)}
```

wherever you want to render the list